# VBA Set XML Element to value in variable for XML Post

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am using XML Import to populate a spreadsheet to pull transactions from the cloud. After importing the data, I need to update the status to "6" to indicate Synched, and send it back to the service.  There is a unique ID to each transaction, which I'm trying to populate, so when I post, it selects the correct record.

The response is showing that the ID is not being sent. *"Could not find object to update with id:None."*  The hard-coded fields seem to be working properly. When I run in debug, the value of SndID is set correctly.

I've tried using " + SndID + " which is what I'm using on my XMLImport (see code below for setting that variable) for variable date ranges, but get the same response.

```
L2LConnect = "https://mycompany.clousdservice.com/api/1.0/spares/
 auth=password&issued__gte=" + cYesterday +  
"&issued__lt=" + cToday + "&limit=1000&format=xml&site=1"
```

Any ideas as to how I can set the value of SndID to ID for that row? I've also tried sending StrData after setting it.

```
  StrData = "&format=xml&site=1&id=" + SndID +  
 "&status=6&closed=True&LastUpdatedBy=L2LSynch"
```

Which returns the same error. ID = None.

```
' RunUpdate Macro
'
    Dim myTable As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim URL As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim StrData As String
    Dim SndID As String


Sheets("XML Import").Select
Set myTable = Sheets("XML Import").Range("Table2")

For Each rng1 In myTable.Columns(11).Cells
    SndID = rng1.Value  

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "https://mycompany.cloudservice.com/api/1.0/spares/
    auth=mypassword&format=xml&site=1"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.send 
"&format=xml&site=1&id=SndID&status=6
&closed=True&LastUpdatedBy=L2LSynch"
strResponse = objHTTP.responsetext

MsgBox strResponse
 Next rng1


End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
objHTTP.send "format=xml&site=1&id=" & SndID & "&status=6" & _
             "&closed=True&LastUpdatedBy=L2LSynch"
```

Good practice to use `&` and not `+` for concatenating strings.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  Still getting the same response:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <response><success>False</success><error>Could not find object to update with id:None</error></response>

Comment: Are you sure there's a value in `SndID` ?

Comment: When I view it in debug it shows:    : StrData : "&site=1&id=36369&status=6&closed=True&LastUpdatedBy=L2LSynch" : String .  Here are a few other values from the debug window:   
    : responseBody : <The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.
 : status : <This method cannot be called until the Send method has been called
      : text : "FalseCould not find object to update with id: None" : String
      : xml : "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response><success>False</success><error>Could not find object to update with id: None</error></response>

Comment: Difficult to say what the issue might be  - could be related to how the API is set up and not technical issue with your code.

Comment: Tim, got it figured out with some help from the provider. The ID needed to be passed in the URL string, rather than the query string.  Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the provider, the ID (unique key) needed to be passed as part of the URL, not the query string:

```
For Each rng1 In myTable.Columns(11).Cells
 SndID = rng1.Value
 StrData = "status=6&closed=True"

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 **URL = "https://mycompany.provider.com/api/1.0/spares/synchronize/
 " & SndID & "/?auth=password&site=1&format=xml"**
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, True
objHTTP.send StrData

 Next rng1
```

End Sub